# Will apple reject apps built with xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode5

I just want to know that will apple reject app build with xcode5.1 since i ready that you need xcode6 after 1st june , but the apple documentation says you need apps built with 64bit arch and ios8 , and xcode 5.1 has both so it will be accepted ? i just want to know if i am correct .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8 SDK is included in [Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW16) or later. That means you need Xcode 6 to build the app. With Xcode 5.1 you have iOS 7.1 SDK support according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_1.html).